# Result redirection not working with jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm getting a ping result in my servlet.I'm trying to redirect it to another jsp file.

the jsp file for output opens.But nothing shows in it.

This is my servlet main code

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String ip = request.getParameter("ip"); 
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    //  out.println("The ip address is:"+ip+"\n");
        String result = pingTest(ip);
        out.println(result);
        String redirect = "Output.jsp";
        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher(redirect);//Is it good approach to redirect request in ajax based servlet?
        view.forward(request, response);
        }
```

This is my output.jsp page

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Ping Check Result</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html
```

Do I need to add anything in output.jsp?

Comment: Well, there is nothing in the body of your JSP. So why should it display anything? Also, what you're doing is forwarding, (which is fine), but not redirecting, which is a completely different thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your servlet:

```
request.setAttribute("result", result);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/Output.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

In your JSP:

```
<pre>The data from servlet: ${result}</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

your servlet must be :

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

            String ip = request.getParameter("ip"); 
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.println("The ip address is:"+ip+"\n");
            String result = pingTest(ip);
            out.println(result);        
            RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher();
            view.forward(request, response);
     }
```